# Error in maven-plugin : "Parameter 'directory' is not a directory"

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I am using two maven modules of a same project.
One is to create a maven plugin, to get all the files with extension "myextn" of a specified directory.

I am using org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils to get the files.

My sample code is here:

```
File specificationDirectory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+src"+File.separator+"test"+File.separator);
String[] extension = new String[] { "myextn" };
List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(specificationDirectory, extension, true);
```

Another module have the directory and files, and uses the plugin.
I am getting the desired result if the files and directory is available in the plugin module,
I am not getting the result when I have the files in the second module, which uses the plugin. 
When I trying to run the second module, I am getting the following error ,    "Parameter 'directory' is not a directory"

My objective is very simple, I have the files in a directory (secondProject/src/test) within the second module, I want to list down the files in this directory using the plugin which has the logic to do this.

Can anyone please help me to get this objective.